# Detect swipe events on UIPageView below UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

So my problem is the following:

I have a `UIViewController`, in it I have defined a `UIPageViewController` and added its view to the hierarchy and on top of that I have added an `UITableView`.

What I would like is to be able to scroll my `UITableView` (that part works) but also to be able to swipe to change the slides of my `UIPageViewController`.

My problem is that the `UIPageViewController` doesn't detect the swipe gesture at all. If I remove the `UITableView` it works all right of course.

My question is the following: is there any way to pass the swipe events from the `UITableView` to the `UIPageViewController` so both would receive their intended gestures ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have the tableView inside your page view (in the content view controller for a specific page).

If you have two views on top of each other the front one will intercept all the touches and no actions will make it through to the lower views.

Try setting user interaction on the tableView to false to see what I am talking about. Of course this will cause the tableView to become unresponsive. You will need to implement this a different way.

Comment: Problem is that I don't want the information on my table view to be swiped. If I put it inside my pageView then everything moves.

Comment: What exactly are you swiping?

Comment: When swiping my tableview left to right or right to left I want my UIPageController below to respond to the swipe

Comment: Thats impossible because the tableView will intercept all touches before it gets to the pageController. Consider using a swipe gesture recognizer on the tableView instead. Or you can use the swipe gesture to programmatically set the page of the page controller.

Comment: That is the question : how is possible to pass swipes from the uitableview to the uipageviewcontroller. I find it hard to believe that there is absolutely no solution to this

Comment: Why is that so hard to believe. If you have two views on top of each other and they are set to respond to touches. Only the top one will actually receive the touch. Try it out with two buttons. It works the same way. What you are trying to do is not the proper way to do it. Either assign a gesture recognizer to the tableView or place your tableView inside the page view.